# Clone movieclip in ActionScript3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, clone, bulkloader

I'm using BulkLoader to load MovieClips and Bitmaps into my AS3 app. Bitmaps are easy to clone, but I have some problems with complicated MovieClips, which has many children, buttons, symbols, etc.

I've found many ways to clone MovieClips as Bitmaps, but is there a way to clone it as MovieClip, with all its attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are 2 ways :

You can copy Loader :

```
var newLoader:Loader = new Loader();
newLoader.loadBytes(oldLoader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes);
```

or You can get MovieClip class and create new instance of it . But for this You will have to compile external SWF with some document class (You dont have to create .as file , just type there some namespace for this SWF)

```
var movieType:Class = myMovieClip.constructor;
var copyMovie:MovieClip = new movieType();
```

Comment: I'd also consider simply loading the clip to be cloned multiple times, it will hit the browser cache for every subsequent load and it won't require any black voodoo magic trickery.

Comment: @ grapefrukt, I tried your method a long time ago, its only practical to load a couple of files but if you have say 30 copies , when loading the screen will pause still for the same amount of time as actually loading them, but my percentage text will read %100

Comment: Best method is create new instance of existing class (2nd way) , fast , synchronius and take less memory .

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dannyburbol.com/2009/01/movieclip-clone-flash-as3/
http://www.smithmediafusion.com/blog/?p=446

**OR**

```
btn1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);

function btnClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var btn:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
    //duplicate the movielcip (add a new one to the stage)
    var ClassDefinition:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(btn)));
    var myMC:MovieClip = new ClassDefinition;
    //add it to the container
    myMC.x = randInt(0,260);
    myMC.y = 0;
    gravity_mc.addChild(myMC);
}

function randInt(min:int, max:int):int{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```